# refactor capybara javascript dropzone test

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to call a dropzone capybara test multiple times. However, when I call it a second time, the ID has already been used. I'm trying to randomize the ID so it can run multiple times.

```
def drop_in_dropzone(file_path)
  page.execute_script <<-JS
    fakeFileInput = window.$('<input/>').attr(
      {id: 'fakeFileInput', type:'file'}
    ).appendTo('body');
  JS
  attach_file("fakeFileInput", file_path)
  page.execute_script("var fileList = [fakeFileInput.get(0).files[0]]")
  page.execute_script <<-JS
    var e = jQuery.Event('drop', { dataTransfer : { files : [fakeFileInput.get(0).files[0]] } });
    $('.dropzone')[0].dropzone.listeners[0].events.drop(e);
  JS
end
```

Error when calling it 2nd time.

```
Failure/Error: attach_file("fakeFileInput", file_path)

Capybara::Ambiguous:
Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching file field "fakeFileInput"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely just generate a random id number for the input but it might be easier to just only create the fakeFileInput it if doesn't already exist.  This would only work if you don't use the input for any other purposes than in this method, but it seems like that's what you're doing.

```
page.execute_script <<-JS
  fakeFileInput = fakeFileInput || window.$('<input/>').attr(
    {id: '#{fake_input_id}', type:'file'}
  ).appendTo('body');
JS
```

If it did already exist it wouldn't get created again and it would just get reused.